# Salesforce buttons on Lightning

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

In the clasic Salesforce, I have the next button type URL:

[image: Example button URL]

[image: Button details]

In the Opportinity view I add this button correctly and work well:

[image: Op view]

But if i change to Lightning experience.... I cant add this button to view:

[image]

The button dont appear in the options:

[image]

¿Any can help me?

Basically I need a button that opens an external page, passing variables such as the opportune ID ...

I tried with javascript button but I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

After you created a button or link for your object (e.g. Opportunity), you should add it to an appropriate layout.

1. Create a button: Setup -> Object Manager -> Opportunity -> Buttons, Links, and Actions -> New Button or Link
2. Add a button to a layout: Setup -> Object Manager -> Opportunity -> Page Layouts -> [Your layout]

[image]